# Is there a way to send a piece of data through a fetch() command, so it's returned with the response?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm running fetch() in a for loop, looping through an array of strings, and looking to handle each fetch response using a unique value (the for loop variable count).

Is there a way to pass data through a fetch command that's unrelated to the target API and get it back in the response?

Here is the code I have so far. The corresponding HTML has a series of images (pic1, pic2, etc.). I currently have "pic1" hard-coded in the .then(data) response handler, but would like to make that variable.

```
    for (var n = 0; n < arrayLength; n++) {
        console.log('Just inside arrayLength for loop');
        console.log('Search term '+ n +' = ' + lines[n]);
        //Do something

        fetch("https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0?method=album.search&album="+ lines[n] + "&api_key=" + lastfm_apikey + "&format=json")
            .then((response) => {
                // handle the response
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                let tunes = data;
                console.log('n: ' + n);

                let albumArtURL = data.results.albummatches.album[0].image[3]['#text'];
                console.log('albumArtURL: ' + albumArtURL);
                document.getElementById("pic1").src = albumArtURL;

            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                // handle the error
                console.log('Error returned: ' + error);
            });
    }
```

I have reviewed the Last.FM API and there doesn't look like there's a way to just pass a string through from the request back through the response.

Comment: So add it when you get back the response. Seems like what you really want is a Promise.all() so you can keep track of the responses in order.

Comment: Thank you @epascarello. I wasn't familiar with Promise.all(). My challenge is that the string array will eventually have hundreds of lines, so I can't really make a p1, p2, p3, etc. Unless there's a way to create variables with a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over thinking it. You have the data so reference it in your then function.

```js
    for (let n = 0; n < arrayLength; n++) {
      const line = lines[n];

      fetch(`https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0?method=album.search&album=${line}&api_key=${lastfm_apikey}&format=json`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(n, line);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error returned: ' + error);
        });
    }
```

Comment: [facepalm] :) Thanks much @epascarello! I figured I was just being dense. I've never done asynchronous calls before. I added another const, "iteration," which keeps the right counter, unlike "n," which just stays at 3 (after looping through for loop).